# What is the proper ratio of Hit vs Pageview recorded by GA?

Tags: google, google-analytics, page-views

There are big differences between Hit counts on my website and GA's pageview number.
For example, GA shows the below article has only 34 pageviews. As you can see in the picture, I choose Behavior->Site Content->all Pages, select "Page Title" as the primary dimension and then filter the report by entering the webpage's title.
[image]

However, on my website's back end, I see the article has 1412 hits
[image]

I understand that hits are definitely larger than pageview, but such a big difference? I must have missed something here. For other articles on the same website, averagely hits are 3 times Pageview count on GA. Is this normal?

Answer (score 1):

I think 4 possible reasons:

## 1. Your visitor was disabled the JavaScript.

Google analytics use javascript to detect visitor so if your visitor that view your page not enable the JS, it would be count.

## 2. Your views were generated by bots

GA will not count pageviews from bots like googlebot, bingbot, and other, but your backend maybe count it.

## 3. Your GA code is not placed correctly

Please check your GA code. It's common simple mistake.

## 4. Your visitor page view was filtered

Google will filter some traffics including bot, your own, and also [Excluded internal traffic](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034840?hl=en)